# Secure WebApp in Wildfly 25 using OpenID Connect (OIDC) without installing a Keycloak client adapter

Tags: wildfly, keycloak, openid-connect

My Webapp is deployed in Wildfly 25.0.1.Final and is secured using OpenID Connect (OIDC).
WildFly 25 enables you to secure deployments using OpenID Connect (OIDC) without installing a Keycloak client adapter.

It is configured like this:

web.xml

```
<login-config>
     <auth-method>OIDC</auth-method>
</login-config>
```

OIDC.json

```
{  
   "provider-url": "${auth.server.url}",
   "ssl-required": "external",
   "client-id": "myClient",
   "public-client": true,
   "confidential-port": 0
}
```

described here:
http://www.mastertheboss.com/jbossas/jboss-security/secure-wildfly-applications-with-openid-connect/

Everything works fine.
My WebApp is secured, it redirects to keycloak for authorization and keycloak sends the tokens to my webapp.
But, **on each request** in my Webapp the Wildflyserver sends **about 100 requests** to the keycloak Server for loading metadata from OpenID provider.

```
13:33:38,405 INFO  [org.wildfly.security.http.oidc] (default task-3) ELY23004: Loaded OpenID provider metadata from 'http://keycloakserver:8180/auth/realms/myRealm/.well-known/openid-configuration'
...
...
13:33:39,480 INFO  [org.wildfly.security.http.oidc] (default task-3) ELY23004: Loaded OpenID provider metadata from 'http://keycloakserver:8180/auth/realms/myRealm/.well-known/openid-configuration'
```

This coudn't be correct, the performance couldn't be sufficient.

In Wildfly 23 (with Keycloak adapter) I didn't see this messages!

Anyone with same experience?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue and documented here:  https://issues.redhat.com/browse/ELY-2284

If you upgrade to wildfly 26.0.1 it should be resolved.