# Wildfly and OIDC

Tags: wildfly, openid-connect

We are a Java shop and use maven. Our app is on wildfly 18. Does anyone have any experiences on migrating a wildfly app to OIDC? We were given a security library that we can use to make OIDC calls to, but it requires a config file co-located with this library. Do we need to use a module for this? If so, do we need a particular section filled out in our standalone.xml?

Comment: What are you using for security currently?  OIDC is very easy to support but be careful of some demos - everything assumes Keycloak which may not be the correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

You asked about Wildfly 18. This one for sure needs add-on modules, such as those provided by the keycloak project (https://www.keycloak.org/downloads).

Since Wildfly 25 the OpenID Connect functionality was added to the Wildfly releases, and since then the addon modules are no longer required. In fact, they should no longer get installed as they seem to break Wildfly.

See also

- [Secure WebApp in Wildfly 25 using OpenID Connect (OIDC) without installing a Keycloak client adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70020441/secure-webapp-in-wildfly-25-using-openid-connect-oidc-without-installing-a-key)
- https://docs.wildfly.org/25/WildFly_Elytron_Security.html#validating-jwt-tokens
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2gQO4_7Z5CI